# How do i set up a listener for a firestore document?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, listener

I am making a chat with Ionic and react using firestore as my database. I am storing all the messages in an array `[]` in a document in firestore. And simply want both users to fetch the data again if a message is added. So i basically want to add a listener to my document. My chat is working but you have to reload the page to see new messages... This is my code:

```
const [chats, setChats] = useState([]);

    db.collection("chats").doc(chatId).onSnapshot((doc) => {

                setChats(doc.data().messages)

            });
```

I either i get infinite loops or doc.data() is not defined. Is there a good way to fetch data using this function? Or do you need for example firebase cloud functions?

Comment: The code you shared so far can neither cause an infinite loop, nor is it referencing `doc.data`. Please make sure your question includes the [minimal, complete/standalone code with which anyone can easily reproduce the problem you're having](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, as it contains many more hints on how to maximize the chances that someone can help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem this way:

```
const [chats, setChats] = useState([]);


useEffect(() => {

        db.collection("chats").doc(chatId).onSnapshot(snapshot => {
            updateMessages(snapshot.data())
        })

    }, []);


    function updateMessages(data : any) {

        setChats(data.messages);
    }
```

When i put the listener inside a `useEffect()` hook i solved the problem with infinite loops since a new listener would start each time the state was updated inside the listener. Now the listener is only initialized once when the component is mounted.

And by sending `snapshot.data()` to a function and THEN fetching `data.messages` i solved the problem with `snapshot.data().messages` being undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the piece of code that you shared from the documentation builds a listener to changes on your database, so you don't need any infinite loops.

Quoting this [documentation for realtime updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#web).

> An initial call using the callback you provide creates a document snapshot immediately with the current contents of the single document. Then, each time the contents change, another call updates the document snapshot.

So everytime a new message is sent, `onSnapshot` will be triggered. You can reference `snapshot` instead of `doc` on the callback that you provide and then you can use `snapshot.docChanges()` to see what has changed. Here is an example:

```
db.collection("chats").doc(chatId)
    .onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.docChanges().length > 0){
            //do something
        }
    });
```

**NOTE**: If this is the first snapshot, all the data will be in the list as added changes and you can fetch the data by taking each change individually and referring to it's data: `change.doc().data()`. Also, since you are querying by `chatId`, the array should always have a size of 1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is my first time using Firebase Firestore so I didn't realize "onSnapshot()" put up a listener. But i figured out why i got a infinite loop since i tried to use "setState" inside the listener. That triggers a re-render and a new listener was set up. So i put the "onSnapshot()-listener" inside a "useEffect()" hook so it only triggered once when the component was mounted. And i could retrieve new data as it updated. I realize my question was badly formatted since the setState issue wasn't mentioned. But my chat is now working so thank you for the help!

Comment: Yes i will update my question and answer it! I have already given your answer an upvote but since om under 15 reputation it is not shown publicly.